# Matlab-Unable to correctly print the output of My Code?-

Tags: matlab

I entered the following code while completing an exercise. The output is 3 by one vector consisting of airspeed, angle, and direction. The airspeed and angle is in the form of a number and the direction is in the form of a character.

```
windspeed=[1 3];
groundspeed=[5 3];

north = [0,1];
south = [0,-1];
east = [1,0];
west = [-1,0];
airspeed = 0;
directionans = 0;
angle = 360;
% Begin your code after this line
vertical=[0 1];

airspeed=groundspeed-windspeed;

if (airspeed(1)>0 && airspeed(2)>0)
   direction='NE';
elseif all(airspeed==airspeed.*north)
    direction='N';
elseif (airspeed(1)<0 && airspeed>0)
    direction='NW';
elseif all(airspeed==airspeed.*south)
    direction='S';
elseif (airspeed(1)>0 && airspeed(2)<0)
    direction='SE';
elseif (airspeed(1)<0 && airspeed(2)<0)
    direction='SW';
elseif all(airspeed==airspeed.*west)
    direction='W';
elseif all(airspeed==airspeed.*east)
    direction='E';
end

if airspeed(2)<0
    vertical=south;
elseif airspeed(2)>0
    vertical=north;
end
vertical;

angle=acosd(dot(airspeed,vertical)/(norm(airspeed)*norm(vertical)));
[norm(airspeed) direction angle]
```

I want an output in the form

```
[50 'NW' 80]
```

Instead, the result is

```
'EZ'
```

This could be due to incorrectly assigning a character to a variable. What can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put numbers into a character array, or characters into a numeric array.  To mix data types you need to use a [cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) array, which is achieved with curly braces:

```
>> {norm(airspeed) direction angle}
ans =
  1×3 cell array
    [50]    'NW'    [80]
```

I would expect `[50 'NW' 80]` to be the same as `[char(50) 'NW' char(80)]` which equals `2NWP`.